# DHCP release using scapy

Tags: python, dhcp, scapy

I want to send DHCP release packets to DHCP server on my lan.

I have MAC addresses of the machines for which i want to forge RELEASE packets.

I Googled it, didn't find anything useful. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried sending a DHCP packet having options message-type:release. Basically i was trying to release my own IP. But it didn't work.

```
sendp(Ether(dst=server_mac)/IP(src=my_ip,dst=server_ip)/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(chaddr=my_mac)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","release")]))
```

Comment: You haven't given much information about what you've already tried... I don't know the protocol myself, but I imagine you would simply open a socket to the address of the DHCP server on the default DHCP port, and compose the `RELEASE` instruction according to the DHCP spec, which should be readily available.

Comment: See [this example](http://www.hackdox.com/network-discovery-via-dhcp-using-python-scapy/) and adjust the message type to be release.  If it doesn't work for you, come back and edit your post to include the code you've tried then I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @VishalD See my response below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for taking a stab at it.  There is one important thing to keep in mind with the DHCP release message.  When you send the message to the server, it won't actually cause the IP address to be released on your local machine.  If you are thinking of creating a demonstration of a DOS or some other attack by using RELEASE, you won't have much luck.

The release message simply tells that DHCP server that the client is relinquishing the network address and cancelling the remaining lease.  It is up to the client to stop using the address after it has relinquished it.

In terms of why it might not be working for you, there are a couple of things that come to mind.

1. The mac address might be incorrect, you didn't include how you set my_mac... you can't simply use a string here.  You can use the value obtained from the get_if_raw_hwaddr function.
2. You are missing the client address and transaction ID in the bootp part of the message.
3. You are missing the server identifier, and end in the DHCP options.  If you used a client identifier to obtain the address, you must use this in the release.  The standard dictates this, but not all DHCP servers mandate it.

Here is an example that works for me.  You can find out more about DHCP by reading the [RFC specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) and/or using Wireshark to capture and observe real packets.

```
from scapy import *
fam,hw = get_if_raw_hwaddr('wlan0')    
send(IP(src=my_ip,dst=server_ip) / 
     UDP(sport=68,dport=67) /
     BOOTP(chaddr=hw, ciaddr='192.168.0.101', xid=random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFFFF)) /
     DHCP(options=[("message-type","release"), ("server_id", "192.168.0.1"), 'end']))
```